# Check if Key exists in Firebase

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, firebase

I have been searching for an answer and could not find it.

I am using Swift 3. 
I have a path, let's say firebase/products, and I want to see if a specific product has a key "MainImage". So naturally I'd do something like

```
Database.Child("Products").Child("ProductID").HasChild("MainImage")
```

But there's no method like "HasChild", or "Exists" or anything similar I could find out. Does anyone have the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method that can check for that, you are going to listen to that child and if it has a nil value, then it does not exist.

```
var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

let ProductID = 64646477343

let  requestListenRefo = ref.child("Products/\(ProductID)/MainImage")

    requestListenRefo.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in  

       let value = snapshot.value as? String

        if(value == nil)
        {
            // doesn't exist
        }

     })
```

Comment: requests/Value is the path to my specific product ? It's difficult to understand this code

Comment: Can I use "String" instead of "NSString" ?

Comment: I am trying it now, have some debugging to do. I'll write here asap with results

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to check existence of the snapshot using `snapshot.exists()`

**Swift**

```
dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

dbRef.child("Users/user1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists(){
        print("user1 exists")
    }else{
        print("user1 exists doesn't exists")
    }
})
```